# Load custom page between place-order-click and thank-you-page

Tags: magento, tracking

I'm currently trying to integrate Econda tracking in the one page checkout process of a magento webshop with the special requirement that the tracking which is normaly done on the thank-you-page already is done once the customer clicks the place-order-button (between button click and redirect to payment provider or thank-you-page). The tracking code itself is dynamically created by an magento extension and injected as html into the phtml file of the thank-you-page. By loading that phtml the information is sent. Also the order in magento must exists before the tracking code can be injected (means place order button must already be clicked).

Currently I'm trying to create an "invisible" phtml, which is loaded once the customer clicks place-order-button and which contains the tracking code. This page should be shown for some seconds and then forward/redirect to either the payment provider or the thank-you-page. This is where I'm totally lost.

I have an observer on the event that is fired once the order is complete/saved. This observer calls an action within my model. But the model can not load/show a phtml.

How can I load a custom phtml-file once the customer clicks the place-order-button, show this phtml for some seconds, and then dynamically forward to either payment provider or thank-you-page?

Answer (score 0):

The Cart Success page, by its very nature is the place that you should be putting any e-commerce tracking Javascript or markup.

It's the very first thing to be delivered to the browser once all the necessary order processing has gone on in the back end. Delivering them to an interim page for only a few seconds seems cumbersome and ultimately inefficient. It's possible, but it's bad practice.

Do you have any particular reason why the success page is insufficient? I can't seem to find that in your question.

Loading a new block into your success page is an easy process. Learn some more about Layouts and Templates (Maybe try [Alan Storm's tutorial here](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates)) and use this method.

Comment: Totally agree and this is the way it is working atm. But my customer wants it to be changed. Reason behind is that customers paying through a payment provider and leaving before reaching the thank you page, don't get tracked. Goal would be to track any orders in the moment the "place order" button is clicked and later all unpaid orders will be "reverted"/"removed" in tracking while paid orders stay.

Comment: You probably need to manage your client's expectations a little better. One of the hardest things about working for clients is learning how and when to say no. Sounds like this is a case where you should put your foot down. Putting an additional page in there is not a good way to track conversions. Why not just use Magento's order reporting? I get that customers can be difficult, but there has to be a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There would be two more options:

- You could add your tracking to the on click event of your button
- You could use server side tracking using the econda PHP SDK

Here's how you can add tracking to click events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function trackIt() {
   window.emosPropertiesEvent({
       siteid: "my-site.de",
       content: "CONTENT-LABEL"
   });
  }
</script>
<tag onclick="trackIt();">content</tag>
```

Be careful using click event tracking in links, it will not work if your page unloads before the tracking event was send.

I could not find the english version of the econda PHP SDK documentation, so sorry, here are the German docs: https://support.econda.de/display/INDE/PHP-Helferklasse

As already mentioned, your thank-you page is the best place to add tracking. An additional reason is, that normally you want to track if a customer really ordered or not. Payment pages are common problems, so it makes no sense to add "order successful" tracking calls before.